# my Node.js Application's reaction rate is very slow

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

First, I'm not good at speaking English.

I'm trying to write code as Node.js based on [Fingersquared](https://github.com/FingerSquared/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Node-Express-LED-Blink) in Raspberry Pi.

So, I want just control my RPi'GPIO. But when I click the button, `console.log` shows very slowly or not at all (but when I click each buttton at first time very quickly react)

When I check the cpu rate, it is just normal (less than 2%).

what is my fault ?  :(

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
 , routes = require('./routes')
 , http = require('http')
 , path = require('path')
 , gpio_led = require('./routes/led');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 52237);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/led/:num/:switch', function(req,res){
        var num = req.params.num
          , sw  = req.params.switch;

        console.log('LED ' + num + ' is ' + sw + '.');
        //gpio_led(num,sw);
})


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
        .row
                .six.columns.centered
                        .panel
                                .row
                                        h4.text-center LED_01
                                        .six.columns.text-center
                                                a.button.large.right.LED1_ON ON
                                        .six.columns
                                                a.button.large.left.LED1_OFF OFF
                                .row
                                        hr
                                        h4.text-center LED_02
                                        .six.columns
                                                a.button.large.right.LED2_ON ON
                                        .six.columns
                                                a.button.large.left.LED2_OFF OFF
                                .row

        script(type='text/javascript')
                $('.LED1_ON').on('click', function(){
                        $.get('/led/1/on');
                });
                $('.LED1_OFF').on('click', function(){
                        $.get('/led/1/off');
                });
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more details. If you do a `console.log` before `$.get('/led/1/on');` how fast do you see it? If it's slow then your problem is in the execution speed of JS in the browser. If not then it might be that HTTP GET is slow (maybe even a cache problem?). Try timing that (your browser's debug console should help). If not then the server itself might be slow, try timing it and see what's slowing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `res.send('ok')` to your handlers.  The browser is waiting for a response to the first button click and never gets it.  That is probably what is causing the delay.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's Working good. 

i don't know why but just i try to add res.sendStatus(302), but is not work.